# Send a javascript command to a Webview using variables gotten with an EditText

Tags: javascript, android, variables, webview

I am in the process of creating a simple webapp for which the user wouldn't have to input his credentials each time he opens the website (no possibility to save the password). I managed to find the form's fields and submit action and it is possible through Crome's console to login when the following lines are submitted.

```
document.getElementById('zonePwd').value="Password"
document.getElementById('zoneId').value="Id"
GInterface.traiterEvenementValidation()
```

Now, on my webapp, I'd like to know if it would be possible to do the same thing using strings after the user fills a dialog with both information.

Be sure to say so if I'm not clear enough

Thanks

PS: I'm very new with JS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommand you to create a javascript function like :

```
function setCredentials(id, pass)
{
    document.getElementById('zonePwd').value=pass;
    document.getElementById('zoneId').value=id;
    GInterface.traiterEvenementValidation();
}
```

And then from your app code

```
String id = "myid"; //Get val from the dialog
String pass = "mypass"; //Get val from the dialog
webview.loadUrl("javascript:setCredentials('"+id+"','"+pass+"')");
```

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: Thanks! 
I'd have a few more questons, though. I did search a bit but just to be sure, I'd have to put the function inside a HTML file, with the script tag nd put that file in a assets/www folder, but how exactly would I call the function from the java file?

Is `webview.loadUrl("javascript:setCredentials('"+id+"','"+pass+"')");` enough? Without precising in which file the function would be, I mean?

Comment: Yep, just put the javascript into your HTML within the <script> tag. You do not need to specify any file, your function will be available as soon as the DOM will be loaded.

Comment: Thanks! That clarifies a lot of things for me! :)