# WebView: Wait until input field exists before starting a javascript function

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

I have a function to load on a website once its two input fields are loaded.

```
function setCredentials(name, key){

    document.getElementById('zoneIdent').value=name;
    document.getElementById('zonePwd').value=key;
    GInterface.traiterEvenementValidation();

}
```

It is contained in a `auto.html` in the `*root of project*/assets/www/` folder. (I tried putting it in the `/res/assets/www/` folder but I get the following from AndroidStudio : `Android Resource Packaging: [QuickPronote] invalid resource directory name: C:\Users\Yann\DEV\workspace\QuickPronote\res/assets`

I have to use this function on this type of website : `http://81.192.152.242:8001/mobile.eleve.html?FD=1`. Note that the website doesn't load quickly.

I'm using the following code :

```
    myWebView.loadUrl(String.valueOf(url));
    myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:setCredentials('" + name + "','" + key + "')");
```

where `url`, `name` and `key` are strings that user has defined.

I tried it, even with dummy text, the two fields are completed and the validation action should be launched but it seems that either the function was loaded too quickly, or either it wasn't lauched at all, because once the website is fully loaded, there is neither the values apearing or an error message saying the credentials are wrong.

If your solution includes the use of external plugin-ins/libs like JQuery, tell me so.

PS: Not using PhoneGap or anything.
[Here's where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17558602/send-a-javascript-command-to-a-webview-using-variables-gotten-with-an-edittext) I got my code from in the first place.

Comment: If your `setCredentials()` function is kept in a local scope or a module inside some JS file then it won't work, as you will need reference to the module in order to call its functions. If its a global function then surely it will be invoked.

Comment: Also in Android, the string arguments that you pass in a JS function through Java code are received in object form by JS. So just check whether the function is called properly by using console.log() for the argument values received. I do notice that you have used proper syntax of quotes for passing arguments as strings, but still its good to check how it is received

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, make sure you've set javascript enabled on the webview,

`webView.loadUrl(String.valueOf(url));`
`webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`

then add a listener to load the name / key once the page has finished.

```
 webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            view.loadUrl("javascript:setCredentials('" + name + "','" + key + "')");
        }
    });
```

**edit**:

I think I found your problem.  The lack of the javascript "setCredentials" method in the page:  `http://81.192.152.242:8001/mobile.professeur.html?FD=1`...  did you forget to add that?

when I change the above `onPageFinished` method to this:

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('zoneIdent').value='test name';");
    }
});
```

the "Identifier" field is populated with "test name" on that page.

Comment: Well, that didn't work. The input fields are still blank. [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/TaNl0Zv.png)

Comment: Just to confirm, make sure you add the line `webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);` in your `onCreate`  function

Comment: And then first check whether javascript functions are really executing by simply calling `alert()` or something from Java code. Once that works, try calling one of your own JS global functions from your file. These are just the basic sanity tests that you can perform to know things are setup well

Comment: Line added. Both `myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                view.loadUrl("javascript:alert('This is from the java file')");
                view.loadUrl("javascript:setCredentials('" + name + "','" + key + "')");
            }
        });` in the .java and `alert('This is from the HTML file');` in the HTML file returned nothing, although my Webview works and JS is activated.